# Content resolver query NullException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-contentresolver

I am trying to fill a ListView with music stored on the external storage volume.

I've isolated the code from a larger project, but the error is the same. In my isolated test program I've got a button which upon pressing, should fill a ListView. I've marked the line which throws the error.

```
package com.example.crtest;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    ListView mList;
    Cursor cu;
    ContentResolver cr;

    public void fillMeUp(View view) {
        Log.i("FillMeUp", "FMU start.");
        String[] proj = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM };
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Log.i("FillMeUp", uri.toString());

        // This is where I get an FATAL EXCEPTION
        cu = cr.query(uri, proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1", null, null);
        Log.i("FillMeUp", "Query finished. " + (cu == null ? "Returned NULL." : "Returned a cursor."));

        Log.i("FillMeUp", "FMU with some text.");

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cu,
                new String[] { "bla" },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
                );
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.i("FillMeUp", "FMU mlist done.");
    }
}
```

This is what LogCat spits out.

```
07-19 23:07:09.613: E/Trace(30502): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-19 23:07:09.763: D/libEGL(30502): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
07-19 23:07:09.763: D/libEGL(30502): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-19 23:07:09.768: D/libEGL(30502): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
07-19 23:07:09.768: E/(30502): Device driver API match
07-19 23:07:09.768: E/(30502): Device driver API version: 17
07-19 23:07:09.768: E/(30502): User space API version: 17
07-19 23:07:09.773: E/(30502): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Mon May 13 15:55:05 KST 2013
07-19 23:07:09.803: D/OpenGLRenderer(30502): Enabling debug mode 0
07-19 23:07:12.408: I/FillMeUp(30502): FMU start.
07-19 23:07:12.408: I/FillMeUp(30502): content://media/external/audio/media
07-19 23:07:12.408: D/AndroidRuntime(30502): Shutting down VM
07-19 23:07:12.408: W/dalvikvm(30502): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bcc930)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3606)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17362)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3601)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     ... 11 more
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     at com.example.crtest.MainActivity.fillMeUp(MainActivity.java:44)
07-19 23:07:12.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30502):     ... 14 more
```

I'm relatively new to Android, but I've worked with Java before. My programming skills, while rusty, are usually okay. But I'm at a loss here. Been working on that problem for two days now, using Google and Stack Overflow got me nowhere.

Comment: where do you call `fillMeUp` method and where is ContentResolver initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Your Content resolver is null, also if you want to get all the music saved on external storage use context.managedQuery. look this: [Android external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457470/android-external-storage) or [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore).

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
cr = getContentResolver();
```

This will return the ContentResolver corresping to current context.